# Default value of a pointer in a new std::map entry

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

So I have the following `std::map`:

```
std::map<int, float*> map;
```

This map is accessed using its `operator []`:

```
float *pointer = map[123];
```

Now if the key 123 did not exist in the map, the value of the pointer will be undefined. Is that correct? To make sure it is:

```
template <class T>
struct PtrWithDefault {
    T *p;
    PtrWithDefault() :p(0) {} // default
    PtrWithDefault(T *ptr) :p(ptr) {}
    PtrWithDefault(PtrWithDefault other) :p(other.p) {} // copy
    operator T *() { return p; }
};
std::map<int, PtrWithDefault<float> > map;
```

Now doing the same ensures the correct initialization of the pointer. Is there other way around it? This is kind of ugly solution. My ultimate aim is speed:

```
std::map<int, float*> map;
float *p;
std::map<int, float*>::iterator it = map.find(123);
if(it != map.end())
    p = (*it).second; // just get it
else
    map[123] = p = 0;
```

Is this going to be faster than the solution with default pointer? Are there better ways to do this?

**EDIT**

Ok, this was completely silly of me. As Brian Bi correctly says, the pointer will be initialized automatically, due to zero-initialization. Value initialization is there since C++03, while C++98 (which is the only available standard in Visual Studio 2008) does not have that.

Anyway, it is readily verified as:

```
std::map<int, float*> map;
typedef float *P;
float *p = map[123], *p1 = P();
```

Both `p` and `p1` are indeed null, no need to worry about a thing.

Comment: Why not just *test* it?

Comment: Should be `it != map.end()`

Comment: Or [Read The Fine Manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map) on the particular?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg we're developing some multiplatform library, we can't possibly test it on all the compilers. Even testing on major compilers only would take some time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the key is not found in the map, the inserted value is value-initialized (§23.4.4.3/1). So no need for a wrapper; the pointer inserted will be a null pointer.

Comment: Man, I should really read the standard these days. This is great.